# Como posso botar um if nessa pesquisa mysql quando não retornar nenhum resultado?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

como botar um if e else nesse codigo para quando a busca no banco de dados não retornar nenhum valor?

```
include_once("conexao.php");
$sql= "SELECT FROM tb_nome WHERE nome LIKE '$pesquisar%'";
$salvar = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
while ($linhas = mysqli_fetch_array($salvar){
    echo "Nome: ".$linhas['nome']."<br>";
    echo "Nome: ".$linhas['telefone']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Use `mysql_num_rows($salvar)`, ficaria algo como `if(mysql_num_rows($salvar) == 0){ //faça algo se não houver dados }else{/ /faça algo se houver dados }`

Comment: muito obrigada pela ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta assim:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($salvar) > 0){
    while ($linhas = mysqli_fetch_array($salvar){
        echo "Nome: ".$linhas['nome']."<br>";
        echo "Nome: ".$linhas['telefone']."<br>";
    }
}else{
    echo "Nenhum resultado foi encontrado.";
}
```

Comment: muito obrigada amigo

Comment: Eu quem agradeço por poder ajudar, se puder marcar a resposta eu agradeço. Qualquer duvida estamos ai.